# jquery-bootgrid how to use load event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to use bootgrid plugin (1.2.0) events.
I read the documentation and I thought I had figured out how to do it

```
var grid = $("#grid").bootgrid({
    ajax: true,
    url: "grid.php",
    caseSensitive   : false,
    rowCount        : [25, 50, -1],
    columnSelection : false
}).on("load.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function() {
    alert('before load data');
}).on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function() {
    alert('after load data');
});
```

Unfortunately only the loaded event seems to work, in fact, the alert "before load data" does not appear.
What is the right way to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You have to bind load event before initializing Bootgrid itself.

```
$(function(){
    $("#grid").on("load.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function() {
        alert('before load data');
    }).bootgrid({
        ajax: true,
        url: "grid.php",
        caseSensitive   : false,
        rowCount        : [25, 50, -1],
        columnSelection : false
    }).on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function() {
        alert('after load data');
    });
});
```